# Segfault on PyDict_New() and python >= 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, cpython

I have a weird issue with my python/c library. Everything is working fine with python >=3.7 and < python 3.10.
With python >= 3.10, the python script segfaults. running gdb on it shows that is segfaults on PyObject* ret = PyDict_New();

I've searched python 3.10 and 3.11 release notes but can't find anything related (i was searching for a removed function, changed behaviour, etc).

the code is :

```
extern "C" PyObject* compute(const char* path, int b, int h, int f, int z, int m, int mf, char* output) {
    PyObject* ret = PyDict_New();
    // some code
    return ret;
}
```

Segfault is also there if i remove entirely the code and just let PyDict_New()

Any idea ? I have a gut feeling that i'm missing something stupid, but can't find what.
Thanks

Comment: Please share the whole code (like initialization and stuff). [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Tagged `ctypes`, so did you load the DLL with `PyDLL`?  Make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably used `CDLL` or `WinDLL` instead of `PyDLL` to load the library.  Using the Python API requires using `PyDLL` to maintain a lock on the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock).  I was able to load with `CDLL` and Python 3.9 but not 3.10 or 3.11 so that reproduces your issue, but it is undefined behavior to call Python APIs without the GIL held.  All three Python versions work with `PyDLL` as expected.

test.cpp

```cpp
#include <Python.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
PyObject* compute() {
    PyObject* ret = PyDict_New();
    return ret;
}
```

test.py

```py
import ctypes as ct

lib = ct.PyDLL('./test')
lib.compute.argtypes = ()
lib.compute.restype = ct.py_object
print(lib.compute())
```

Output:

```
{}
```

Comment: Thanks you ! that was precisely my error. However, i'm a bit puzzled thinking about why it worked until python 3.10 (since it worked with CDLL for years). Again, thanks you, very much !